# Reusing an existing test in same spec file in playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

**Problem Statement** : In **test.spec.ts** I have a describe block inside which I have a test. In the same file, I have another describe block inside which I have a test that needs to call the test in first describe block and then proceed with it's rest of the steps.

**test.spec.ts**

```
test.describe("Describe block 1", async () => {
 test("a test that creates a chart of a given type(assume that you can pass the type from an environment variable) and validate if it is created correctly", async()=>{
  step1
  step2
....
})
})

test.describe("Describe block 2, async () => {
 test("a test that firstly need a new chart to proceed with it's other steps", async()=> {
  call the test in first describe block and get a chart created and then proceed with other steps
  step2
  step3
....
})
})
```

**Why I would need to do such a thing** - There is a valid use case where in the first describe block there is a test that creates a chart of a given type and validates if the chart is created correctly. In one of the test in second describe block I need to again create a chart and then do some other validations basis the type of the chart. This will ensure that I am not touching any existing chart and have a valid sample to work with.

Is there a way to achieve the same in playwright efficiently. What other options do I have?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Re-use function, not test.
> Remember a test can fail for unexpected behavior but not an function unless  there are coding errors.

Create a re-usable method in your page object to create charts.

Pass all the variable data inputs to it as parameters and use it anywhere as a reusable function to create different kind of charts based on its parameters.

**Note**: Don't create test dependencies(like calling one test from another or use data created in one test in another test after) its a bad practice as for the simple reason if one test fails the dependent tests will also fail in chain reaction.

> Keep your tests isolated to each other as much as possible.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to avoid such dependencies. I don't want to use existing charts. I need a newly created chart for my test every time to have a consistent sample every time I run my test validations.

Comment: Yes , as I mentioned create a method to create chart in your page object and call in tests wherever required.

Comment: can you please suggest me some repos or example of page object model that scales very well for a large app. I am writing down the tests for a large application and following page object model. I have been following up best practices that I have learnt in playwright but I want to see other projects as well that I can refer to see if my direction of writing the tests are right and will scale well. Thank you.

Comment: My suggestion would be don't get in to premature optimization and just focus on keeping your code DRY.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: Moving the code to a new function will keep my code DRY but I noticed that essentially what I have done is moved the code related to a test to a function and calling it wherever required in my spec file. This is kind of dependency because the code that I have moved "creates a chart of a given type" and there is a test where I create a chart of a given type say type A and validates if it get created where I call this function. Also there is another test where I need a chart of type A, I call this function. Hence this latter test will become dependent on creation test case.

Comment: Both tests are dependent on an function but not on each other, there is an difference.

Comment: Function does not create a chart of a single type only . Various kind of charts can be created using parameters with same function.

Comment: Even if a chart creation process becomes lengthy, it can be broken down into sub functions who do their small bit in the process.