How do I declare a Playwright test once and use it many times?
I have a number of common tests which I'd like to be able define once and use many times, in various combinations in order to test different workflows. Ideally I'd put these in a library and import them where I want to use them.
// library.js

test('test1', async(){   
  await test.step('1', async()=>{});
  await test.step('2', async()=>{});
  await test.step('3', async()=>{});
})

test('test2', async(){   
  await test.step('1', async()=>{});
  await test.step('2', async()=>{});
})

test('test3', async(){
  await test.step('1', async()=>{});
  await test.step('2', async()=>{});
  await test.step('3', async()=>{});
  await test.step('4', async()=>{});

})

export test1, test2, test3;

I'd then like to import and use them in various combinations...
// workflow.js

import {test1, test3} from 'library'

test.describe.serial('workflow1', ()=>{  

  test.beforeAll('', async({browser})=>{
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('/');   })

  test1();

  test3();

})

Is there a way to do this that does not rely upon custom fixtures or page objects? The closest I've come is this...
// library.js
const {expect,test} = require('@playwright/test')

export const homepage = async(page)=>{

  await test.step('1', async()=>{
    // do something with/on/in page
  });

  await test.step('2', async()=>{
    // do something with/on/in page
  });

  await test.step('3', async()=>{
    // do something with/on/in page
  });

}

// workflow.js

const {homepage] = require('library/library')

test.describe.serial('', ()=>{

  let page;

  test.beforeAll('', async({browser})=>{
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('/');  // base URL as defined in config
  })

  test('', async()=>{
    await homepage(page);
  })
})


You could create a function, or a class, that expects a test object and returns all the tests...

@hardkoded you can use fixtures as well to perform actions you need every time or you define a POM and prepare your expectations there.

This is sort of a strange request, so more context seems necessary. Usually, when you write a test, you only want to run it once. If there are parameters that change, it'd be good to show your actual use case, because there's probably a sensible solution, but it's hard to make a recommendation with just these generic pseudocode stubs.

@ggorlen. Okay, so some context. I have to write tests for complex systems which have multiple varied workflows. I have written a test for each workflow step. Let's call these tests a, b, c, d, e, f, and g. These are essentially building blocks for more complex tests. Workflow 1 might be tests a, b, and c while workflow 2 might be tests a, c, d, and e. I want to write once and use often.

Is there a problem with making the content of these workflows normal vanilla JS helper functions? Do they require test-specific parameters, or are they exactly the same every time?

@ggorlen Any CRUD data is read from a JSON file located in a relative folder. Any URLS are relative to the base URL defined in the Playwright config file. Thanks.

I would simple suggest Data driven/Or Keyword driven tests based on pure functions so that you can mix and match as required flexibly.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947116/1831456

It's a bit difficult to grasp your exact use case. There could be a very clear-cut way to generalize whatever you're trying to do, but in lieu of that, here's your tests cleaned up and working:
// workflows.test.js
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1
import {test1, test2, test3} from "./library";

test.describe("workflow1", async () => {
  test("block 1", async ({page}) => {
    await test1(page);
    await test3(page);
  });
});

test.describe("workflow2", async () => {
  test("block 1", async ({page}) => {
    await test2(page);
    await test3(page);
  });
});

// library.js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

const p = console.log;

const test1 = async page => {
  await test.step("1", async () => {
    p("test 1 step 1");
    await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {
      waitUntil: "commit",
    });
    const h1 = page.getByRole("heading", {level: 1});
    await expect(h1).toHaveText("Example Domain");
  });
  await test.step("2", () => p("test 1 step 2"));
  await test.step("3", () => p("test 1 step 3"));
};

const test2 = async page => {
  await test.step("1", () => p("test 2 step 1"));
  await test.step("2", () => p("test 2 step 2"));
};

const test3 = async page => {
  await test.step("1", () => p("test 3 step 1"));
  await test.step("2", () => p("test 3 step 2"));
};

export {test1, test2, test3};

Output:
Running 2 tests using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:5:3 › workflow 1 › block 1 (60ms)
test 1 step 1
test 1 step 2
test 1 step 3
test 3 step 1
test 3 step 2
  ✓  2 pw.test.js:12:3 › workflow 2 › block 1 (27ms)
test 2 step 1
test 2 step 2
test 3 step 1
test 3 step 2

  2 passed (627ms)

Note that test blocks can't be called as functions at the time of writing, only test.step can be abstracted away like this.

Another revenge DV. Feel free to ignore, the answer clearly works.

Upvoted because this 'Note that test blocks can't be called as functions at the time of writing, only test.step can be abstracted away like this.' is pretty much the answer I was looking for.
